# Wait for two PubSub data streams before joining data

Tags: streaming, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have two independent `PubSub` data streams. Each of them receives a notification. I want to retrieve the files whenever a notification appears and join those files using `CoGroupByKey`. Both files are JSON content and have a common key.

How can I be sure that I've received both files before starting the join process?

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    file_1 = (
            p
            | "file_1: read file notifications" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="sub1").with_output_types(bytes)
            | "file_1: WindowInto" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
            | "file_1: read file" >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
        )
        
    file_2 = (
            p
            | "file_2: read file notifications" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="sub2").with_output_types(bytes)
            | "file_2: WindowInto" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
            | "file_2: read file" >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
        )
        
        # Flatten the collected PCollections
        joined_data = ({'file_1': file_1_collected, 'file_2': file_2_collected}
                       | "Flatten collected data" >> beam.Flatten())

        # Perform the join operation
        result = (joined_data
                  | "CoGroupByKey Join" >> beam.CoGroupByKey())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [state & timers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers) for that use case. If they have the same key, produce tuples (key, value) from each one of the streams, and have some state variables filled when you see each file. Once you have seen both files, then do something else and clear the state. You can try to use a `BagState` and a `CombiningState` or `ValueState` counting, and a timer as "fallback" in case you don't see any of the two files, so you don't hold state forever.

In the stateful DoFn, you would already have together both files, so there is no need to use `CoGroupByKey`.

In the snippet above, if the files are produced with similar timestamps they will fall in the same window. But if they are not produced with a similar timestamp, then windowing would not work. That's why I prefer a solution based on state & timers for that specific problem.